# How do I make my mouse close an app without clicking on the close icon?

Tags: windows, mouse

I have a Logitech MX 1000 mouse with the latest SetPoint software. Even though I used Setpoint to set a button to do a Close action. It doesn't work with many apps. How do I make my mouse close an app using one of the programmable buttons, without clicking on the app's close icon?

Comment: Do the applications that it doesn't work with respond to Alt+F4?

Comment: All the apps can be closed by alt-F4.

Comment: Set the mouse button as a macro for ALt+F4 then

Comment: @Ramhound Macro support is for gaming mice.